# Gridview in update panel not reflecting changes using ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a asp.net GridView which uses ObjectDataSource to fetch the data. The GridView is inside of UpdatePanel. I want to filter the data on click on different LinkButtons. For this I have written new `SelectMethod` and `SelectCountMethod` for each LinkButton and setting these methods to ObjectDataSource on the click of LinkButton. After setting both methods I am calling `GridView.DataBind()` method. All `SelectMethod` return type is `DataSet`.

I've debugged the code I'm getting the data from the database but the gridview is not updating. Also the `GridView_DataBound` event is not hitting when LinkButtons are clicked. Following things I tried which doesn't worked:

- Set LinkButton `CausesValidation="True"`.
- Set UpdatePanel `UpdateMode="Always"`.
- Created ObjectDataSources with `SelectMethod` and `SelectCountMethod`
  for each LinkButton and setting `GridView.DataSource` to click of
  link button.
- Also tried setting `FilterExpression` and `FilterParameters` on click of link button. This does hits the `ObjectDataSource1_Filtering` event and correct parameters are passing.

**GridView with UpdatePanel**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="grdViewHeaderDivider"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            OnSorting="GridView_Sorting"
            OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging"
            GridLines="None"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView" EventName="Sorting" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView" EventName="DataBound" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lblTotalUploaded" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lblUploadedNS" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lblUploadedSA" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**ObjectDataSource**

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OnFiltering="ObjectDataSource1_Filtering" SelectCountMethod="GetApplicationsCount" SelectMethod="GetApplications" TypeName="TestApp.Applications" SortParameterName="sortExpression" EnableCaching="false" EnablePaging="True" >
        <SelectParameters>

        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**LinkButton Click**

```
protected void lblTotalUploaded_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = (LinkButton)sender;

            //ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "ApplicationName='{0}'";
            switch (btn.CommandName)
            {
                case "lblTotalUploaded":
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "GetApplications";
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectCountMethod = "GetApplicationsCount";
                    break;
                case "lblUploadedSA":
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "GetScore";
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectCountMethod = "GetScoreCount";
                    //ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("ApplicationName", "Candy Crush");
                    break;
                case "lblUploadedNS":
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "GetNoScore";
                    ObjectDataSource1.SelectCountMethod = "GetNoScoreCount";
                    //ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("ApplicationName", "Clash of Clans");
                    break;
            }
            ObjectDataSource1.Select();
            GridView.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem. Posting solution in case someone needs it.

The issue is with ObjectDataSource's SelectMethod. When I click on LinkButton, Update panel reset the SelectMethod and use which are defined at design time.

I solved it by using only 1 SelectMethod for all LinkButtons and use session parameter to be passed to SelectMethod and get the data as per session value.